# How to combine pandas df so that rows with permuted col1 and col2 values can be merged containing only one combination & summing a count column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, permute

I want to combine the permuted col1 and col2 values into one row. containing only the first combination & summing the count column of both. Is there an easy way to do this in pandas?

The example data frame and output: For example, in the below data frame I want to combine rows with values A, B, and B, A and sum their count column. Same for rows with values C, D, and D, C and sum their count values as well. I want to keep the rest of the rows in the data frame as is.

INPUT:

| col1 | col2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 3 |
| C | D | 2 |
| B | A | 5 |
| E | F | 2 |
| G | H | 8 |
| D | C | 5 |
| I | J | 4 |

OUTPUT:

| col1 | col2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | 8 |
| C | D | 7 |
| E | F | 2 |
| G | H | 8 |
| I | J | 4 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `.groupby` according sorted col1/col2:

```py
x = (
    df.groupby(df[["col1", "col2"]].apply(lambda x: tuple(sorted(x)), 1))
    .agg({"col1": "first", "col2": "first", "count": "sum"})
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
  col1 col2  count
0    A    B      8
1    C    D      7
2    E    F      2
3    G    H      8
4    I    J      4
```

Answer (score 1):

We can [`np.sort`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) across rows to ensure the same values appear in the correct columns (for example `A B` and `B A` both become `A B`), then [`groupby sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html) on the now ordered columns:

```
# Sort Across Rows
df[['col1', 'col2']] = np.sort(df[['col1', 'col2']], axis=1)
# Accumulate counts by col1 and col2 (now in same columns)
df = df.groupby(['col1', 'col2'], as_index=False)['count'].sum()
```

`df`:

```
  col1 col2  count
0    A    B      8
1    C    D      7
2    E    F      2
3    G    H      8
4    I    J      4
```

---

Setup (DataFrame and imports):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'G', 'D', 'I'],
    'col2': ['B', 'D', 'A', 'F', 'H', 'C', 'J'],
    'count': [3, 2, 5, 2, 8, 5, 4]
})
```